# TYPO3 Images not resizing in front and backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.x

I am working on an installation of TYPO3 7.4. When you upload an image to a standard content element it will show full size images under the 'Images' tab instead of the usual thumbnails. Also, setting the width or max-width has no effect on the images on the site.

Anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: Probably your imagemagick/graphicsmagick setup needs to be fixed. Check the install tool, there are tests for it.

Comment: @Jost Ok, thanks. Unfortunately I don't have access to that...

Answer (score 1):

As in a comment it is probably a problem with the ImageMagick / GraphicsMagic settings.

You can proof it in the InstallTool:

[image: Install Tool TYPO3 7.6]

If you can not access it, you can check the urls of the images if they show the true path like: f**ileadmin/user_uploads/test.jpg** and not something like **fileadmin/_processed_** then it means that there is no conversion happened.

To solve this issue you have to change your graphic settings in the LocalConfiguration.php or in Install Tool.

You can find it under `'GFX'`.

This is an example setting for ImageMagick:

```
'GFX' => [
    'colorspace' => 'sRGB',
    'im' => 1,
    'im_mask_temp_ext_gif' => 1,
    'im_path' => '/usr/bin/',
    'im_path_lzw' => '/usr/bin/',
    'im_v5effects' => 1,
    'im_version_5' => 'im6',
    'image_processing' => 1,
    'jpg_quality' => '80',
],
```

In most cases you have to check the **`'im_path'`** property as it can be different by different providers.